# Iterating through an array to create if statements in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration

I have the following arrays of prices and dates.

```
prices = [60, 70, 80]

dates = [earliest_date, middle_date, latest_date]
```

Assuming the arrays are equal length, how can I iterate through the arrays to create an if statement along these lines for variable array lengths?

```
if Date.current < dates[0]
  price = prices[0]
elsif Date.current < dates[1]
  price = prices[1]
...
else
  price = some_default_price_value
end
```

Comment: you can combine them both first.. and then iterate over them.

Comment: If anyone can give me insight into why this question was downvoted, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
price = prices.find.with_index {|_, i| Date.current < dates[i] } || DEFAULT_PRICE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have something of this sort:

```
for i in 0..prices.size
  if Date.current < dates[i]
    price = prices[i]
    break
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
price = prices.zip(dates).find{|_, date| Date.current < date} &.first \
|| some_default_price_value
```

`&.` is to make `first` safe in case an element satisfying the condition is not found.

Comment: Please explain `&.first`. A variant is `(prices.zip(dates).find{|_, date| Date.current < date} || [some_default_price_value, :anything]).first`.

Comment: I still don't understand. I presume that if `find` returns a two-tuple, `&.first` extracts its first value, and if `find` returns `nil`, `&.first` returns `nil`, but I don't recognize the `&.` terminology.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If `find` returns `nil` and `first` is applied to it without `&.`, then it will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) with an argument that is a `lambda`.

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def price(prices, default_price, dates, curr_date)
  dates.zip(prices).find(ifnone=->{ [nil, default_price] }) { |d,_| curr_date < d }.last
end
```

**Examples**

```
prices = [60, 70, 80]
default_price = 90
dates = [Date.today-1, Date.today+1, Date.today+3]
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-02-16 ((2457435j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-02-18 ((2457437j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-02-20 ((2457439j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 

price(prices, default_price, dates, Date.today-2) #=> 60
price(prices, default_price, dates, Date.today)   #=> 70 
price(prices, default_price, dates, Date.today+2) #=> 80
price(prices, default_price, dates, Date.today+4) #=> 90
```

**Other ways**

Here are two other ways that have not been mentioned:

*#1 Use an inline `rescue`*

```
def price(prices, default_price, dates, curr_date)
  dates.zip(prices).find { |d,_| curr_date < d }.last rescue default_price
end
```

*#2 Add a higher limit*

```
def price(prices, default_price, dates, curr_date)
  (dates+[curr_date+1]).zip(prices+[default_price]).
    find { |d,_| curr_date < d }.last
end
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the size will be same for both, and the order doesn't matter as well.

```
prices = [60, 70, 80]
dates = [earliest_date, middle_date, latest_date]
prices.each_with_index do |p,index|
   puts "price: #{p}"
   puts "Date: #{dates[index]}"
end
```